# Why (String, Int) is expected instead of (Char, Int)?

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension

I am completely lost why the following doesn't work:

```
takeRange :: Int -> (a,Int) -> [(a,Int)] -> [(a,Int)]
takeRange n elem list = dropWhile (\x -> snd x < snd elem) (takeWhile (\x -> snd x < (snd elem) + n) list)

seriesLargestProd :: String -> Int -> Int
seriesLargestProd "" _ = 0
seriesLargestProd _ 0 = 0
seriesLargestProd s n = maximum [foldl1 (*) $ map (read . fst) (takeRange n pair zipped)
                                | pair <- zipped, snd pair <= lastStartingIndex] 
                                    where zipped = zip s [1..]
                                          lastStartingIndex = (length s) - (n-1)
```

The error messages I get:

> ```
> Couldn't match type `Char' with `[Char]'
>     Expected type: (String, Int)
>       Actual type: (Char, Int)
>     In the second argument of `takeRange', namely `pair'
>     In the second argument of `map', namely `(takeRange n pair zipped)'
>
> Couldn't match type `Char' with `[Char]'
>     Expected type: [(String, Int)]
>       Actual type: [(Char, Int)]
>     In the third argument of `takeRange', namely `zipped'
>     In the second argument of `map', namely `(takeRange n pair zipped)'
> ```

If anyone's interested, this is supposed to be an answer to problem 8 of [Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function you're mapping `read . fst` has the type `Read a => (String, b) -> a`.  So `map (read . fst) :: Read a => [(String, b)] -> [a]`.  But `zipped` has the type `[(Char, Int)]`, and `takeRange` returns the same type of list as its input.

As an aside, you could implement `takeRange` as

```
takeRange n elem list = take n $ drop (snd elem) $ list
```

You're doing extra work by counting the indices manually, and as @sepp2k mentions this would be even more idiomatic with pattern matching on the tuple.

Answer (score 2):

> Why a String is expected, when zip will clearly "disunite" the string into individual characters?

Because `read` takes a String. In order to convert a single digit to an integer, use `digitToInt`, not `read` (alternatively you could also use `read [theChar]` to create a single-character string and convert it, but there's no need for that here as `digitToInt` exists).

PS: Instead of `snd x` and `snd pair`, it would be more idiomatic to use pattern matching to name the elements of the pair individually.